# Faut-il dire « que » ou « qui » ?

Tags: pronoms

Qu'est-ce qui s'utilise avant les pronoms possessifs: **qui** ou **que** ?

Exemples:

(1) « Un jeu **qui** *me* fait plaisir" ou « Un jeu **que** *me* fait plaisir » ?

(2) « Un garçon **qui** *se* lève tôt » ou « Un garçon **que** *se* lève tôt » ?

(3) « Elle a fait un dessin **qui** *m*'a touché profondément » ou « Elle a fait un dessin **que** *m*'a touché profondément » ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il faut dire « qui » quand le pronom relatif est sujet (tous tes exemples) et « que » dans le cas plus rare où le pronom est complément d'objet : « Avec tous les ennuis que s'attire Jean, nous n'allons jamais nous en sortir. »